# Cannot create a file by this path "file://localhost/users/admin/Desktop/" by XCode

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

My username on Mac OS is "admin", and I used NSOpenPanel to get the output path, the result is:

```
file://localhost/Users/admin/Desktop
```

However I use `NSFileManager` to `createFileAtPath`, nothing happens. If I change the path to `/Users/admin/Desktop` , the file will be created successfully. Could you please tell me why?

Also I found on Mac OS X 10.8 I get the Desktop path is "file://localhost/Users/admin/Desktop", but on 10.9 I got "file:///Users/admin/Desktop"...strange

Comment: This is not a path, this is an URL...

Comment: I have solved it. use [url path] can get the NSString path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. use [url path] can get the NSString path.